# Inifinitely many primes $p\equiv -1 \mod12$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, arithmetic-progressions

I haven't been able to prove this statement from my Elementary Number course:

**There are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p\equiv -1 \mod12$.**

From [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.facm/1229442627) I know that there exists a "Eulcidean style" proof for this problem. I think it should be related to quadratic residues.

Thanks,

EDIT: I know it follows from Dirichlet's theorem, but I am expected to find an elemntary proof.

Comment: It is a special case of the Dirichlet Theorem.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by it equals $-1$?  Do you mean it equals $11$?  Is this the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing.

Comment: @Jared Yes $-1 \equiv 11 \mod 12$ because $11-(-1) \mid 12$.

Comment: Consider using \pmod instead of \mod, it formats nicely

Comment: Maybe Wilson's theorem would help, which states that $p$ is prime iff $(p-1)! \equiv -1$ mod $p$. Then the problem becomes proving that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that there is an $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $12k \mid (p-1)! + k + 1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose there are only finitely many primes of this form, say  $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Let $P = p_1\dots p_n$ denote their product. Consider now the following expression:
$$Q = 12P^2-1$$
Then we observe the following:

**Every prime divisor of $Q$ is $\pm 1 \pmod{12}$**

**Proof.** Let $q$ be a (necessarily) odd prime such that $q \mid 12P^2-1$. Then $$3(2P)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$$
So $3$ is a quadratic residue. But as an application of the [quadratic reciprocity law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity), this only happens when $q \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{12}$.

So every prime divisor is of the form $12n+1$ or $12n-1$. But they cannot all be of the form $12n+1$, otherwise the product would also be of this form. We conclude that there is a prime of the form $12n-1$ dividing $Q$ and this prime cannot divide $P$, so we're done.

Comment: Thanks Jef,

1. Did you mean to say " Let q be a (necessarily) odd prime such that $q \mid 12P^2-1$" ?  ($P$ instead of $Q$?)

2. Why does that imply 3 is quadratic residue?

Comment: Yes, it's indeed a typo, thanks for letting me know :-)

Comment: @guest $3$ is a quadratic residue because $3\equiv \left(\frac{1}{2P}\right)^2\pmod{\! q}$

Comment: Thanks a lot!

For future readers:
One must first assume $q \neq p_i$, because then $2P$ is not invertible $\pmod q$, because $gcd(q,2P) = q$.

Comment: Yes that's true. But it readily follows from the fact that $q \mid 12P^2-1 $

Answer (score 2):

The answer comes directly from [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions): Let us have the sequence $12k+11$. The members of the sequences are all $\equiv -1$ (modulo $12$), and according to Dirichlet's theorem, since $gcd(11,12)=1$, there are infinite amount of primes in our sequence.

Comment: We should find out if the OP is allowed to use Dirichlet.  I doubt it because if he had learned Dirichlet he probably wouldn't be here asking.

Comment: I gave you a "+1" because of the correctness. However, as noticed, the theorem is not elementary!

Comment: Honestly, I commented this several minutes ago. (+1 though)

Comment: Yes, then it would better for Atvin to at least mention that, though Atvin might also come up with that independently. :)

Comment: Thanks @Atvin, but the proof should not use Dirichlet, as we haven't shown it yet.

Comment: It is quite easy to see that it can be proved by Dirichlet, I didn't even check the comments. If you want something else, than you should have wrote it in your question. :)